# Selenium and xpath: finding a div with a class and onClick function not working

Tags: java, selenium

When I click the image with id **`draggerImg_3_1`**, it selects the item but the **`onclick`** function is not getting called, when I write.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("draggerImg_3_1")).click();
```

This is the HTML of that button

```
<div class="videoDragger" onclick="click_Handler('vid-Boxing-','1',1)" onmouseover="mouseOver_Handler('vid-Boxing-','1')" onmouseup="mouseUp_Handler('vid-Boxing-','1')" onmousemove="mouseMove_Handler('vid-Boxing-','1')">
<img src="images/check_mark_blank.png" class="markerDragMe" id="draggerImg_3_1" height="20" width="20"></div>
```

Here in this image I have selected 4 items and as you can see below they are getting selected but they are empty as **`onClick funtion`** related to that button is not getting triggered.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried performing the clicks manually and it behaves differently? It's odd that the clicks are doing something but you say the onclick isn't working. The DIV has the onclick but you are clicking the IMG... that shouldn't matter but you could try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure as to the exact layout of the elements and what parts you're trying to click without seeing more of the source code.

However, with that being said, the `onclick` function is on the `div`, rather than the `img`. Try using your `.click()` on the `div`.